# Implementing MATLAB-like zooming feature in PyQt5 for log scale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, pyqt5

I am using this implementation to zoom with mouse scroll in matplotlib canvas:

```
def zoom_on_scroll(self, event):
    if event.inaxes is not None:
        base_scale = 1.1
        self.canvas.axes.figure.canvas.toolbar.push_current()  # so the home button still works
        cur_xlim = self.canvas.axes.get_xlim()
        cur_ylim = self.canvas.axes.get_ylim()

    xdata = event.xdata  # get event x location
    ydata = event.ydata  # get event y location

    if event.button == 'up':
        # deal with zoom in
        scale_factor = 1 / base_scale
    elif event.button == 'down':
        # deal with zoom out
        scale_factor = base_scale
    else:
        # deal with something that should never happen
        scale_factor = 1
        print(event.button)


    new_width = (cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0]) * scale_factor
    new_height = (cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0]) * scale_factor

    relx = (cur_xlim[1] - xdata) / (cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])
    rely = (cur_ylim[1] - ydata) / (cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])

    self.canvas.axes.set_xlim([xdata - new_width * (1 - relx), xdata + new_width * relx])
    self.canvas.axes.set_ylim([ydata - new_height * (1 - rely), ydata + new_height * rely])

    self.canvas.draw()
```

I tried to recalculate the new_width and new_height  variables, also the relx and rely variables with np.log10() (numpy), but I cant figure out how to modofy this code to get the zooming right on logarithmic scale. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can't you just use an instance attribute for the current scale? In the `__init__` make a `self.scale_factor = 1` then you always multiply/divide with the same ratio, like `self.scale_factor *= 2` for zoom in and `self.scale_factor /= 2`.

Comment: Thanks. My main problem though, is that the position of the mouse compared to the curves should stay the same, but on logarithmic scale it changes. Or the same thing explained differently: If I scroll up (zoom in), then I leave the louse on the same place and scroll down (zoom out), I should get back the original figure (same X and Y limits as at the begginning). But thats not what happens on logarithmic scale.

Comment: That's because you should set the target rectangle with an inverse function that remaps the mouse position in the new coordinate system when zooming out. Can you please provide a full [mre]?